# Aggregate rows based by one column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a data set that looks like this:

| report_id | category_id | product_id | year_month | total_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | A | 1 | 202201 | 10 |
| 10 | A | 1 | 202202 | 16 |
| 10 | A | 2 | 202201 | 11 |
| 10 | A | 3 | 202201 | 8 |
| 10 | A | 4 | 202201 | 12 |
| 10 | A | 4 | 202202 | 15 |
| 10 | B | 7 | 202202 | 19 |
| 10 | B | 8 | 202204 | 17 |
| 10 | B | 9 | 202203 | 9 |

I am trying to summarize the table where I can aggregate by year_month if category_id = A without any aggregation for category_id = B; all products for category_id = A can be referred to as 'misc'.

The desired data set should look like this:

| report_id | category_id | product_id | year_month | total_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | A | misc | 202201 | 41 |
| 10 | A | misc | 202202 | 31 |
| 10 | B | 7 | 202202 | 19 |
| 10 | B | 8 | 202204 | 17 |
| 10 | B | 9 | 202203 | 9 |

I am totally lost as to how to produce this data set.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where did product_id of "misc" come from?  Please explain the logic in your post.

Comment: One approach would be two queries, one for A and one for B and then union the results with `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use case to format the column product_id according to the value in category_id and then group by the result.

> ```
> create table myTable(
>   Report_id int,
>   Category_id char(1),
>   Product_id int,
>   Yearmonth varchar(6),
>   total_sales int
>   );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into myTable values
> (10   ,'A',   1,  202201  ,10),
> (10   ,'A',   1,  202202  ,16),
> (10   ,'A',   2,  202201  ,11),
> (10   ,'A',   3,  202201  ,8),
> (10   ,'A',   4,  202201  ,12),
> (10   ,'A',   4,  202202  ,15),
> (10   ,'B',   7,  202202  ,19),
> (10   ,'B',   8,  202204  ,17),
> (10   ,'B',   9,  202203  ,9);
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> Select
>   Report_id,
>   Category_id,
>   Case when category_id = 'A' then 'misc'
>   Else product_id end Product_ID,
>   Yearmonth,
>   Sum(total_sales) total_sales
> From myTable
> Group by 1,2,3,4;
> ```
>
> ```
> Report_id | Category_id | Product_ID | Yearmonth | total_sales
> --------: | :---------- | :--------- | :-------- | ----------:
>        10 | A           | misc       | 202201    |          41
>        10 | A           | misc       | 202202    |          31
>        10 | B           | 7          | 202202    |          19
>        10 | B           | 8          | 202204    |          17
>        10 | B           | 9          | 202203    |           9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3c98eb9c75d34c04d50ed98f2d32c575)*

Comment: @forpas: ["Why the downvote?": These comments are useless, and should never be posted in the first place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393914/724039)

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate over:

- total_sales with the SUM function
- product_id with the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) in a conditional way using the [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if) function

```
SELECT report_id,
       category_id,
       IF(GROUP_CONCAT(product_id) LIKE '%,%', 
          'misc', 
          GROUP_CONCAT(product_id))            AS product_id,
       year_month_,
       SUM(total_sales)                        AS total_sales
FROM tab
GROUP BY report_id,
         category_id,
         year_month_
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tcg5LqHEVZGC5yemYy9jkG/1).

Note: this is a generalized solution, in case your 'misc' value should ever be found in any category, rather than the only category 'A', as per your specific sample data.